# I don't want to include audio in screen recordings this app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, audio, videochat

We are currently creating a video calling app.
I don't want to include audio in screen recordings this app.
It seems that Zoom allows this, but I can't seem to found a specific how to do.
Is it something to be controlled with AVAudioSession?

I configured audio settings before start webrtc the following.

```swift
private func configureAudioSession() {
       let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
       do {
           if audioSession.category != .playAndRecord {
               try audioSession.setCategory(
                AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord,
                    options: [
                        .defaultToSpeaker,
                        .allowBluetooth,
                        .allowBluetoothA2DP,
                        .mixWithOthers
                    ]
               )
               try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
           }

           if audioSession.mode != .videoChat {
               try audioSession.setMode(.videoChat)
           }

           try audioSession.setInputGain(1.0)
           
       } catch {
          // handle error
       }
}
```

I tried several categories and modes of AVAudioSession.